# XSD.EXE Generate code for element with subnodes with unknown names

Tags: c#, xsd, names, xsd.exe

I am trying to automate a process and what I would like to accomplish is to obtain some sort of array of the sub elements of an XML node.

(I am sorry if I am not using the correct names here, corrections from literate people are always welcome :) ), I have searched but I havent found something

So, this is a sample of the XML section:

```
<SectionName>
 <NodeWithNameA>value for a</NodeWithNameA>
 <ThisHasAnotherName>and another value</ThisHasAnotherName>
 <AndThereAreManyNodesWith> the same behaviour</AndThereAreManyNodesWith>
 <MoreNodes>many more</MoreNodes>
</SectionName>
```

Currently the XSD.EXE generates an XSD, but generates a Type for each of the nodes of SectionName, and what I would like, is perhaps a list of Name/Value objects or similar.

I have tried to modify the XSD declaration it like this:

```
        <xs:element name="SectionName" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>

                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
```

But at the end, when I load the file and de-serialize it, I get an empty class..

```
/// <remarks/> 
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")] 
[System.SerializableAttribute()] 
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")] 
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)] 
public partial class SectionName{

}
```

How I could declare the XSD, so I can retrieve all the items inside, regardless the name... or... option two, could be to get some XNode or another object which I can iterate...

Comment: Can you give an example of what you would like the class to look like?

Comment: Hi Mike, It could be something like:

public XmlNode Elements {get;set;}

or a NameValueCollection, HashSet, Dictionary or an array of objects

Comment: Can you change the xml so that the "unknown" elements are like <Node key="NodeWithAName" value="value for a"/>

Comment: Unfortunately it is not under my control to change that XML, but I think that I could pre-process the XML and convert it into that. I would need to load it directly with XmlDocument, reach the nodes of "SectionName" and then iterate trough nodes